# Finding the metric tensor from a line element

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Given the following line element, write the metric tensor
$$\mathrm ds^2 = -\mathrm{d}t^2 + r\,\mathrm{d}r^2 + \text{sin}\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta \,\mathrm{d}r.$$

I know that the correct formula to use is $\mathrm ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm dx^{\mu}\mathrm dx^{\nu}$.

My question is, should the $g_{\theta r}$ term be sin$\theta$ or $\frac{1}{2}$sin$\theta$ because of the symmetry of $g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: There is indeed a 1/2.

Comment: Thanks @knzhou, the other $\frac{1}{2}$sin$\theta$ should be the $g_{r\theta}$ component?

Comment: Yup. $\hspace{20mm}$

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. Please use this tag in the future for this type of question.